# Parsing in Android and Custom list view

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have use the navigation drawer activity. I want to display customized list after getting data from URL. Here is my navigation drawer activity.

For example: when user click allocation tab on navigation drawer then allocation activity appear with customized list view showing data of URL.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {case R.id.nav_dashboard:
     startActivity(new Intent(this, AdminDashBoardActivity.class));
                    // Handle the camera action
            } }
 else if (id == R.id.nav_allocations) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {case R.id.nav_allocations:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,   

       AdminAllocationActivity.class));
                break;
                // Handle the camera action
            }

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_courseoutline) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_courseoutline:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, CourseOutlineActivity.class));  }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_ranklist) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {case R.id.nav_ranklist:
                    startActivity(new Intent(this,AllocatedTrainerActivity .class));
        }}
// else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
//
//        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

when user click on allocation tab then allocation activity open and showing result of parsed data on customized list but it is not happening. please guide me.Here is my Allocation activity.

```
package vu.bc110201891.btg.AdminActivities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import vu.bc110201891.btg.Adapters.AdminAllocationAdapter;
import vu.bc110201891.btg.AsyncTasks.AdminAllocationTask;
import vu.bc110201891.btg.Models.AdminAllocation;
import vu.bc110201891.btg.R;

public class AdminAllocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String json_string;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    ListView listView;
    AdminAllocationAdapter contactAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_allocation);

        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        contactAdapter=new AdminAllocationAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_admin_allocation);
        listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);

        json_string=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
        try {
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("courseDataSet");

            int count=0;
            String name,email,moblile;

            while (count<jsonArray.length()){


                JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                name=JO.getString("id");
                email=  JO.getString("company_id");
                moblile=JO.getString("user_id");
                AdminAllocation contacts=new AdminAllocation(name,email,moblile);
                contactAdapter.add(contacts);
                count++;
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my adpater.

```
package vu.bc110201891.btg.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import vu.bc110201891.btg.Models.AdminAllocation;
import vu.bc110201891.btg.R;

/**
 * Created by bc120402700 on 9/23/2016.
 */
public  class AdminAllocationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {




    List list=new ArrayList();
    public AdminAllocationAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }



    public void add(AdminAllocation object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
   @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row=convertView;
        AllocationHolder contactHolder;
        if (row==null){


            LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_allocation,parent,false);
            contactHolder=new AllocationHolder();
            contactHolder.tx_name= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            contactHolder.tx_email= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
//            contactHolder.tx_mobile= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_mobile);
            row.setTag(contactHolder);
        }

        else {

            contactHolder=(AllocationHolder)row.getTag();


        }
        AdminAllocation contacts= (AdminAllocation) this.getItem(position);
        contactHolder.tx_name.setText(contacts.getName());
        contactHolder.tx_email.setText(contacts.getEmail());
        contactHolder.tx_mobile.setText(contacts.getMobile());
        return row;
    }
 static class AllocationHolder{
TextView tx_name,tx_email,tx_mobile;
}
}
```

here is my asyn task.

```
package vu.bc110201891.btg.AsyncTasks;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import vu.bc110201891.btg.R;

/**
 * Created by bc120402700 on 9/23/2016.
 */
public class AdminAllocationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String json_url;
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        json_url = "http://mantis.vu.edu.pk/bridging_the_gap/public/AllocateAdminService";
    }
    String JSON_STRING;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
try {
 URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");

            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()}
        return null;}
 @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values); }
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);}
}
```

this is my model class.

```
package vu.bc110201891.btg.Models;
public class AdminAllocation {
private String name,email,mobile;
public AdminAllocation(String name, String email, String mobile){
        this.name=name;
        this.email=email;
 this.mobile=mobile;
 } public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
 public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
 public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }public String getEmail() {
        return email; }
public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set adapter to listview after getting the values

```
listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

add this line after this coding

```
 json_string=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
        try {
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("courseDataSet");

            int count=0;
            String name,email,moblile;

            while (count<jsonArray.length()){


                JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                name=JO.getString("id");
                email=  JO.getString("company_id");
                moblile=JO.getString("user_id");
                AdminAllocation contacts=new AdminAllocation(name,email,moblile);
                contactAdapter.add(contacts);
                count++;
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The correct code

```
json_string=getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");
        try {
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("courseDataSet");

            int count=0;
            String name,email,moblile;

            while (count<jsonArray.length()){


                JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                name=JO.getString("id");
                email=  JO.getString("company_id");
                moblile=JO.getString("user_id");
                AdminAllocation contacts=new AdminAllocation(name,email,moblile);
                contactAdapter.add(contacts);
                count++;
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

Comment: still giving error and not showing result. this is my error.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at vu.bc110201891.btg.AdminActivities.AdminAllocationActivity.onCreate(AdminAllocationActivity.java:33)

Comment: May be any integer or double value should be read as a String. Please check with that